# Can I use firebase to pass data from an Android app to Java programa(JSE & Swing) and vice versa?

Tags: java, android, swing, firebase

I would like to know if I am able to use Firebase to pass data from an Android App to a Java program made using Swing (this one will be installed in a computer) and vice versa (PC to an Android app).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Firebase has a java SDK which can access the same project as your Android app.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup